# Android - Parameter to execute dynamic query

Tags: android, sqlite, dynamic, parameters

I have a query in my main application, that shows all the registers of my database.

I have a button in my application that gets into another activity. There, i can filter my query ( for example, i have a book table and i just want books from an author and with an specific price)

So with a spinner i select my options and with an intent and put extra i pass the variables to my principal activity, so i can show the query filtered.

Here is the example

```
String selGrado =  this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("grado");


 String query = "Select * FROM Incidentes WHERE 1=1";

   if () query+= " AND codGr='"+selGrado+"'";



     Cursor d = db2.rawQuery(query,null);
```

So, i want my query to execute with the parameter selGrado that i filled in my "filter" activity.  Which condition should i put?  Because when application starts, i want to show all registers so its no problem avoiding the filter,  and i want to execute just Select * from Incidentes ..     and if i query trough FILTER activity, i want the query knows about which option i selected.        is there any way to ask if  the getExtra i receive is null or something like that? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can check extras by using the intent method hasExtra:

```
this.getIntent().hasExtra("grado");
```

but you could also check to see if selGrado is null

```
if(selGrado!=null)
```

a better way to do this is with the regular query instead of rawquery

```
String selection = null;
String[] selectionArgs = null;

if(getIntent().hasExtra("grado")) 
{
    selection = "codGr=?";
    selectionArgs = new String[]{getIntent().getStringExtra("grado")};
}

Cursor c = db2.query("Incidentes",null,selection, selectionargs, null);
```

Comment: thanks, but i have a problem.  When i first put String selGrado =  this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("grado");
my program doesn't show the info.  So if i dont have data in that intent because i recently open the application and didnt put a filter, my query crashes.    So i cant ask if hasExtra is null, i dont know how to solve this!

Comment: hasExtra returns boolean (true or false) never null. So you can always use it.  If this returns true then you can get that extra and check to see if it is null.